# Compact Proof that the constant $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k.k!}$ is irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers, rationality-testing

In an answer some time ago I referenced a short proof that the constant $e$ is irrational by A. R. G. MacDivitt and Yukio Yanagisawa (The Mathematical Gazette , Volume 71 , Issue 457 , October 1987 , pp. 217)

[What is the shortest proof that there is an irrational number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4234700/what-is-the-shortest-proof-that-there-is-an-irrational-number/4236911#4236911)

I think the technique can be applied to prove that the constant $U_1=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k.k!}$ is irrational.

**Step 1:** Suppose $U_1$ is rational; $U_1$ being defined by the infinite sum, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k.k!}$; that is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k.k!}=\frac{m}{n}\tag{1},$$

where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers.

**Step 2:** Multiply both sides of (1) by $D(H_n).n!$, where $D(H_n)$ is the denominator of the Harmonic Number $n$ (simplified form for neatness, although this choice is not essential to the proof) thus

$$D(H_n).n!\left(1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2\times 2!}+\frac{1}{3\times 3!}+...+\frac{1}{n.n!}  \right) \\+\frac{D(H_n)}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{D(H_n)}{(n+1)(n+2)^2}+\frac{D(H_n)}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)^2}+...=D(H_n)n!\,\frac{m}{n}\tag{2}$$

so that $S=\frac{D(H_n)}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{D(H_n)}{(n+1)(n+2)^2}+...$ is a positive integer, with $nS \ge \frac{D(H_n)}{(n+1)}$.

**Step 3:** Construct contradiction.

$nS\ge \frac{D(H_n)}{(n+1)}$ can be written $(n+1)S-\frac{D(H_n)}{(n+1)} \ge S$, implying that

$$\frac{D(H_n)}{(n+2)^2}+\frac{D(H_n)}{(n+2)(n+3)^2}+...\ge \frac{D(H_n)}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{D(H_n)}{(n+1)(n+2)^2}+...;$$

which after comparing both sides of the inequality term by term can immediately seen to be a contradiction. (Assuming I haven't made a mistake)

Assuming this is correct I am not sure if the same method can apply to the alternating sum
$$U_2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k.k!}$$

As the sum $U_2$ is unconditionally convergent, adjacent positive and negative terms in the sum can be brought together giving positive terms only, thus

$$U_2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2k-1)^2+2k}{(2k-1)2k(2k)!}$$

but unfortunately this gives a numerator depending on $k$ and I think this stops the same proof from working.

**For added background**

$U_1$ and $U_2$ are related to the Euler-Mascheroni Constant, $\gamma$, thus

$$U_1=-\gamma+Ei(1)$$
$$U_2=\gamma-Ei(-1)$$

where $Ei(x)$ is exponential integral.

The Euler-Gompertz constant $\delta$ is
$$\delta=-e\,Ei(-1)=eU_2-e\gamma$$

**Additional Comment**

It should also be noted that

$$U_1=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k-1)!}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)(2k)!}$$

and

$$U_2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k-1)!}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)(2k)!}$$

Therefore $U_2$ the number we are trying to prove irrational is equal to

$$U_2=U_1 -2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)(2k)!}$$

which shows how infuriatingly elusive irrationality proofs can be.

Comment: I think a summation where one of the terms has zero denominator is not desirable.

Comment: Sorry that typo now fixed

Comment: Is $D(H_n)$ the denominator in simplified form?

Comment: @KamalSaleh: I don't think it matters. A denominator in simplified form is neater. Looking at it now, I think the proof works using $n!$ instead of $D(H_n)$ as well - as long as the the before $S$ part is definitely an integer. and there is no variation in the numerator across the terms in the inequality. Interesting.

Comment: @JamesArathoon sure it doesn't matter, but we still need to make $D(H_n)$ well defined. But as you state, $n!$ is sufficient for the proof.

Comment: @KamalSaleh: Edit made, thanks for your comment